# How to write a program that dynamically creates Objects?

Tags: java, user-interface, object, swt

I am trying to write code for my latest class assignment where we create a Harness Record System, the code needs to keep track of Harness's in a system, be able to create new Harnesses and edit/loan/check old ones. I have gone down the route of using a GUI rather than the console as it is easier for the user to use. Although, I'm having trouble coming up with ideas on how to write code that differentiates old Harnesses written into the code, with new Harnesses that overwrite the previous input of the user.

So my question is, is there any way to write a code that can create objects once the user clicks a certain button, so that when that button is clicked the information inputted by the user into that object comes up, rather than just the most recent input of the user.

I know this is a silly and badly worded question, but my brain is just fried at the moment, I'm in need of help.

My code is below, I'm using two different classes and the SWT kit, if anyone could have a look at my code and help me out I would be so grateful, really struggling to find a way to overcome this:

Harness Class: http://pastebin.com/HqJqGfTN

HarnessSelection Class: http://pastebin.com/EE4C2WCs

Answer (score 0):

The 'new' keyword is how you create new object instances. I haven't read all of your code but make sure you understand what the 'static' keyword does - it makes all instances of that class share the same value for that field.  Perhaps all of your harness instances are sharing the same static variables.